# GridBagLayout creates only a single row

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a small problem concerning GriBagLayout. I am trying to create a panel with GridBagLayout which should consist of a **few rows** of Buttons and Labels to change the state of Arduino Pins.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

    public ControlPanel() {
        for (int index = 0; index < 14; index++) {
            GridBagConstraints c_label = new GridBagConstraints();
            c_label.gridx = 0;
            c_label.gridy = index;
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Pin: " + index);
            add(label, c_label);

            JButton inputOutput = new JButton("INPUT");
            //Add Actionlistener here

            GridBagConstraints c_inputOutput = new GridBagConstraints();
            c_inputOutput.gridx = 1;
            c_inputOutput.gridy = index;
            add(inputOutput, c_inputOutput);
        }    
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    }
}
```

The problem I currently face is all labels and buttons are aligned back to back and this looks really messy.
[image]

Comment: Calling `setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` before the for-loop. (The layout should generally be set before adding components)

Comment: Ohh shi*t. I knew it would be really simple to fix. Thank you